# Compare values in two different rows and variables in an iteration

Tags: python, pandas, iteration

Folks,

I have a dataframe with words extracted from text, with columns indicating their location at the text. Say:

```
word    start   end
sugar   10      16
ice     32      35
cream   36      41
```

I want to create a loop to identify when words come together in the text and have ice cream as its own entry:

```
word      start   end
sugar     10      16
ice cream 32      41
```

I tried this, but it raised a **Keyerror**:

```
treats = pd.DataFrame()

for i in range(len(df)):
  if df['end'][i]+1 == df['start'][i+1]:
    word = df['word'][i]+' '+df['word'][i+1]
    start = df['start'][i]
    end = df['end'][i+1]
    i = i+2
  else:
    word = df['word'][i]
    start = df['start'][i]
    end = df['end'][i]
  row = [site,url,ent,word,start,end]
  treats = pd.concat([treats,row])
```

Where did I goof?

**EDIT:** WOW. You brought very, very thoughtful answers. Wish I could give a coffee to each of you. One extra complication I just found out: the solutions work well in the way I was originally defining the problem, but after trying your solutions I found out the df also has words that have been broken in two, so df['end'][x] == df['start'][x+1]. Is there an easy workaround?

**EDIT 2:** As requested, here's the data example of how it got:

```
word    start   end
sugar   10      16
ice     32      35
cream   36      41
choc   120     124
olate  124     129
```

Comment: Can you also share how you defined df? It is impossible for us to know the problem in this way

Comment: I imported a CSV, and the directly relevant columns of the df are those in the first listing.

Comment: (In fact the CSV had been imported previously, with the full text where I got the words from. I ran an entity extraction model which collected the words with start and end. It came out in a list of dictionaries, which I then turned into a new DF from each element.)

Comment: Can you add an actual data example for the new scenario? Perhaps I'm misunderstanding but `35`/`36` is already an example of `df['end'][x] == df['start'][x+1]`?

Comment: What should the output be for the new example? @ouroboros1's answer gives `sugar, ice cream, choc olate` - is this not what you want?

Comment: @jqurious: I'm assuming that the OP means that "choc" + "olate" should become "chocolate". @ OP: I've updated my answer on this assumption: could you please confirm whether this is what you mean? If not, please add the expected result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Edit*: added quicker route to the required `groups` suggested by [@jqurious](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19355181/jqurious).

---

First, let me expand the example `df`, because it gets a bit more complicated when disconnected groups follow each other immediately, and I'm assuming that this might well be a possibility.

**Data**

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'word': {0: 'sugar', 1: 'ice', 2: 'cream', 3: 'hello', 4: 'there', 
                 5: 'world', 6: 'sugar'}, 
        'start': {0: 10, 1: 32, 2: 36, 3: 50, 4: 56, 5: 62, 6: 70}, 
        'end': {0: 16, 1: 35, 2: 41, 3: 55, 4: 61, 5: 67, 6: 75}}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df

    word  start  end
0  sugar     10   16
1    ice     32   35 # join `ice cream` (start: 32, end: 41)
2  cream     36   41
3  hello     50   55 # join `hello there world` (start: 50, end: 67)
4  there     56   61
5  world     62   67
6  sugar     70   75
```

**Solution 1**

The much better route, suggested by [@jqurious](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19355181/jqurious) in the comments:

1. Shift `end` one row forward ([`Series.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html)) and subtract it from `start` ([`Series.sub`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.sub.html)).
2. Check `> 1` ([`Series.gt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.gt.html)) to get start of groups as `True` and apply [`Series.cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) to assign a consecutive number to each group.
3. Apply [`df.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and chain [`.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) to get the relevant aggegrations for each column.

```
g = df['start'].sub(df['end'].shift(1)).gt(1).cumsum()
# like: [0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3]

out = (df.groupby(g).agg({'word':' '.join, 'start':'first','end':'last'}))

out

                word  start  end
0              sugar     10   16
1          ice cream     32   41
2  hello there world     50   67
3              sugar     70   75
```

**Solution 2** (verbose)

```
# get `True` for each row where col `end` + 1 equals next row `start`
s = df['end'].add(1).eq(df['start'].shift(-1))

# create groups for consecutive `True` values in `s`, and reindex
out = (s.diff().ne(0).cumsum()[s]).reindex(df.index)
# like: [nan, 2.0, nan, 4.0, 4.0, nan, nan] (still missing the group value
# for the last member of a group)

# fill the first `np.nan` after each `True` with a shift of `out`
out = out.where(out.notna(),out.shift(1))
# getting: [nan, 2.0, 2.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, nan]

# add another `Series.where` to fill remaining `np.nan` with the index from `df`;
# these will be the `non-group` values
out = out.where(out.notna(),df.index.to_numpy())

# use `out` as a grouper and get the relevant aggegrations for each column,
# resetting the index with `as_index=False`
out = (df.groupby(out, as_index=False)
       .agg({'word':' '.join, 'start':'first','end':'last'}))

# same result as `Solution 1`
```

**Solution Edit (2) OP**

*Edit*: I stand corrected by [@jqurious](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19355181/jqurious) yet once more! Edited the solution below to take his more logical route again.

On the OP's edit. I'm assuming you mean: whenever a value in `end` equals `start` in the next row, then the strings in `word` need to be joined *without a whitespace*. E.g., `choc` + `olate` needs to become `chocolate`. Here's one approach:

1. Where `df['end']` + 1 ([`Series.add`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.add.html)) does not equal `df['start']` ([`Series.ne`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.ne.html)) keep the entries for `word` as is, else add a whitespace at the end (using [`Series.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html)).
2. Apply Solution 1, but now join on an empty string (`''`).

```
# add whitespace
df['word'] = df['word'].where(df['end'].add(1).ne(df['start'].shift(-1)),
                              df['word'] + ' ')

# Solution 1
g = df['start'].sub(df['end'].shift(1)).gt(1).cumsum()
out = (df.groupby(g).agg({'word':''.join, 'start':'first','end':'last'}))

out

        word  start  end
0      sugar     10   16
1  ice cream     32   41
2  chocolate    120  129
```

Comment: I think you can `out = df['start'].sub(df['end'].shift(1)).gt(1).cumsum()`

Comment: @jqurious: I think you're absolutely right. Added this suggestion as the better solution. As mentioned in the initial draft, I already thought I was making things too complicated. Thank you!

Comment: Wow! Thank you for your thoughtful answer and edits. I'm still munching on them to understand how they work, but they definitely do work.

Comment: Thanks for the updated explanation. Just thought I'd add: Instead of adding 'FLAG' - you could add the space. You can then remove the space from the `df['start'].sub(df['end'].shift(1)).gt(1)` rows before grouping on the `.cumsum()`. This allows you to use `''.join()` in the `.agg()` and not have to worry about any checks for existing substrings.

Comment: @jqurious: yet again to the rescue. This really ought to have been your accepted answer! Thank you so much, I trust also on the OP's behalf, for sharing your improvements.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you can use :

```
# is "ice" succeeded by "cream" ?
m = df["word"].eq("ice") & df["word"].shift(-1).eq("cream")

treats = df.groupby(m.cumsum(), as_index=False).agg(
    {"word": " ".join, "start": "first", "end": "last"}
)
```

Output :

```
print(treats)

        word  start  end
0      sugar     10   16
1  ice cream     32   41
```

*Input used :*

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"word": ["sugar", "ice", "cream"], "start": [10, 32, 36], "end": [16, 35, 41]}
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution:

```py
import pandas as pd

data = {'word': {0: 'sugar', 1: 'ice', 2: 'cream', 3: 'hello', 4: 'there',
                 5: 'world', 6: 'sugar'},
        'start': {0: 10, 1: 32, 2: 36, 3: 50, 4: 56, 5: 62, 6: 70},
        'end': {0: 16, 1: 35, 2: 41, 3: 55, 4: 61, 5: 67, 6: 75}}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

m = {s: (w, s, e) for w, s, e in zip(df['word'], df['start'], df['end'])}
out, current = [], None
while m:
    current, s, e = m.pop(min(m))
    while e + 1 in m:
        w, _, e = m.pop(e + 1)
        current = f'{current} {w}'
    out.append((current, s, e))

df = pd.DataFrame(out, columns=['word', 'start', 'end'])
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
                word  start  end
0              sugar     10   16
1          ice cream     32   41
2  hello there world     50   67
3              sugar     70   75
```